# GridView with different background color

Tags: gridview, colors, background-color

I have a GridView with 12 elements.

```
View v;
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 107, 179));
```

I need to have the first 6 elements with a particular color and rest of 6 with another color.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer by myself:

```
    if (position < 6)
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 107, 179));
else
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,91,153));
```